# NSOutlineview with images in cells

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'd like to add images next to my cells in my nsoutlineview.

[image]

I'm having a really tough time doing this. I'm coming from iPhone development, so I was thinking of making a custom cell to do this, but it seems like NSCell is a control, not a view.

I've looked at the SourceView sample code, but it's tremendously confusing. It seems like this should be a really simple task as it's such a common interface component.

I currently have a working nsoutlineview which only has text, and i've implemented the following delegate methods:

```
-outlineView:child:ofItem:
-outlineView:isItemExpandable:
-outlineView:numberOfChildrenOfItem:
-outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:
-outlineView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:byItem:
-outlineViewSelectionDidChange:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [PXSourceList](http://github.com/perspx/PXSourceList).  It does this (using custo drawing), so you can either just use it directly or rip the drawing code into your own app, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has an example on how to do this:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTableViewImagesAndText

Comment: The link to cocoadev is broken.